# Does adding ?.jpg after url really bypasses wifi security? And how?

Tags: security, wifi, internet

So I stumbled upon the following lifehack the other day:

[image: Lifehack]

I currently don't have access to an airport with expensive WiFi but it seems that adding `?.jpg` to any url doesn't cause any problems with the page still loading.

Some questions come to mind:

- Why does websites still load correctly after adding `?.jpg`?
- How would it bypass the type of WiFi security where you first need to add credit to continue browsing?

Comment: http://www.quickmeme.com/img/0c/0cf488d9f77a4dd34ac1ed2053d963b326d25eeec09ae444884804ffadfb251f.jpg

Comment: This is in the best case a question for Super User.

Comment: This would not work at any captive portal I built. If it's true at all, it will only apply to some small subset of access points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In a URI, the question mark signals the end of the path portion of the URL and the beginning of the query string parameters.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)

Normally unrecognized query string parameters are simply ignored, which is why nothing broke when you tested adding `?.jpg`.

As for why modifying the URL like this would change anything when connected to an open wifi hotspot that requires some kind of login or activation code my assumption would be:

- This isn't something that works in general but rather something that works for some particular hotspot solution.
- This solution where it does work would appear to have an http proxy or something similar that inspects requested URLs, query string and all, and allows anything that ends with `.jpg` even for clients that have not yet authenticated. (This check for the full URL, including query string, to end with `.jpg` would appear to be either a bug or a misconfiguration!)

Worth noting is that doing what this tip suggests seems like it could very well be illegal and as such is not such a great idea to suggest to people.